# How to find out the character set of a text file

Tags: conversion, character-encoding, utf-8

Is the a tool (mac or online) that can help me to find out the character set of a text file, and then convert it to utf-8 ?

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/a/762475) is an excellent answer to your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using Windows try downloading [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm). It should recognize the encoding and offers several conversions including UTF-8.

Comment: Nice tool, thank you!!  (my score is 11 so I can't boost your).

Comment: if you need to convert your file: http://www.rishida.net/tools/conversion/

Answer (score 9):

- for linux, use `file -i filename`
- for mac, use `file -I filename`

For instance,

```
$ file -i readme.txt 
readme.txt: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
```

BTW, for converting, use `iconv`， for instance,

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 filename
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not convert

Comment: In speaking of converting, use the command `iconv`. For instance, `iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 filename`

Comment: With `file` command, why did both two files encoded with `big5` and `gb2312` present `iso-8859-1`?